# How to construct a field with 25 elements of a given polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let us say that the polynomial is $x^2 + 5$ and the field is $\mathbb F_{25}$. Hereby $ax+b$ denotes any element of $\mathbb F_{25}$ with both $a$ and $b$ in the field $\mathbb F_5$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: In the field of order $5$, $x^2+5\equiv x^2$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Try $x^2-a$ where $a$ is not a square mod $5$.